# make pages with capabilities given to users based on DB

Tags: asp.net, capability

I'm new to asp.net and trying to figure out how to go about displaying different capabilities to individual users based on what is allowed to them by checking the database.

A good example I think would be like a forum where the admin an turn on and off different capabilities the user can perform. ex. Editing old post, viewing old post, printing posts.

In my database I would have users matched with roles and capabilities.

What would be the best way to "generate" pages customized to each user, where they can see the option to "edit a post" if they had that capability, and not see it if they didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET Membership:

ASP.NET membership gives you a built-in way to validate and store user credentials. ASP.NET membership therefore helps you manage user authentication in your Web sites. You can use ASP.NET membership with ASP.NET forms authentication by using with the ASP.NET login controls to create a complete system for authenticating users.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

You can then show/hide buttons such as "edit a post" by checking if the current user is in the correct role:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx

e.g.

```
ButtonEditPost.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I feel that the roles that the membership offer is limiting. Since it works with giving roles access to certain pages. Where in my application "users" roles can access the same page, but what they see on it could be different. I don't think I would want to create multiple variation of a page and have different roles/capabilities pointing to different ones.